# How to use Photoshop CS6 without an Adobe ID?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6, serial-number, adobe-creative-suite

**Background**

I have a legal Adobe Photoshop CS6 serial number. I have downloaded the Photoshop CS6 from the Adobe website. I have installed it with my legal serial number. Everything until now is fine. When I open my Photoshop CS6, it asks me to sign in with an Adobe ID, which I do not wish to.

How to use Photoshop CS6 without an Adobe ID?

**(Optional) For those who wish to know the reasons, here are they:**

- I do not have an Adobe ID, as I was using Photoshop CS5, which has never forced me to sign in/get one.
- Privacy concern that I do not wish to sign in.
- Most likely I will forget my Adobe ID. What will happen if I forget (not only the password, but both the password and the ID, and also the email linked to it) and I need to reinstall my computer or move my Photoshop to another new computer?

Regardless my reasons, I believe we should not be forced to get an Adobe ID.

**Workarounds**

The best way would be disabling the "ask for ID" dialogue and just let me use the program, by altering some files/registry or blocking the Internet connection, etc. But I have been searching for whole day and it seems no solution works out there yet.

Then I start thinking about some workarounds. **IF** it is really not possible to disable the "ask for ID" thing, I tend to registry a dummy Adobe ID. If so, my concern would be:

**At the time when I need to install my Photoshop CS6 again, can I use the same serial number with another new dummy Adobe ID?**

I guess this question applies to all Adobe products that forces us to have an Adobe ID.

Comment: Unless you link the serial to yourself the key won't be connected to the account.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So I have registered Photoshop with Serial A, and logged in that Photoshop with Account A. Serial A will not be linked to Account A. I will be able to use Account B with Serial A later?

Comment: I just said that.  Unless you add the serial to the account yourself obviously

Comment: Sign in no longer seems to work on this old software (before they went to subscription based).

Comment: On " I believe we should not be forced to get an Adobe ID.": It's part of the offering. Most modern software requires to use an ID to connect the local license with, most likely to control concurrent activations (not necessarily "use") of the software.

Comment: Do you found a solution to the problem? I'm running into the same problem right now with my CS6 version that I bought retail in 2012.

Answer (score -1):

At this point (2021) there is no legal way to have CS6 applications activated and running in a new installstion. The CS6 activation servers were taken offline 2017.